# COM Dll registration fails on Windows-8 64 bit Operating System

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, windows-8

My C++ COM Shell Extension DLL built on Windows 7 64 bit system using Visual Studio 2010.
The DLL registration is failing, When I am trying to register my dll on windows 8 64 bit evaluation version

I did the following steps to register my Dll

1. Created a folder like C:\MyDll
2. Copied the COM dll and the dependent DLL to a folder named  MyDll (Dependent Dlls: MSVCP.Dll, MSVCR.dll,System.Data.SQLite.DLL)
3. Open the Cmd.exe as administrator
4. Executed the following command 
   C:\Windows\System32>regsvr32  C:\MyDll\Test64.dll

I registration steps promted the error message:

> The module "C:\MyDll\Test64.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary
>   is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with
>   the binary or dependent .DLL files. A dynamic link library (DLL)
>   initialization routine failed

Application Event Viewer Error Logs:

> Faulting application name: regsvr32.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time
>   stamp: 0x5010a4f2 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x000000008003f038 Faulting process id: 0xef0 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01cdab0260bf6785 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe Faulting module path: unknown Report
>   Id: 9e7efd80-16f5-11e2-be6f-bcaec589de41 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It crashed with an access violation.  You'll need to debug it.  Set the Debugging + Command to regsvr32.exe

Comment: Can you load it with depends? http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't have any Win8 mahine for devugging the DLL.

Comment: @JPAlioto, the dependency walker logs : Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
I am getting the same error message while loading the DLL on win7 machine. But with this load error, the DLL registers successfully on Win7 64 bit system